# weird symbols in electron javascript

Tags: javascript, electron

On this page in the example code constants are defined with `{}`

https://github.com/electron/electron/blob/master/docs/api/net.md

```
const {app} = require('electron')
```

What does `{name}` do compared to just `name`?

Also, I tried the code above with jquery and I an error "cannot read property request of undefined".

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){

  const {net} = require('electron');
  const request = net.request('https://github.com'); <- here
```

Comment: It's destructuring assignment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment

Comment: The example uses `app.on('ready')`, does it work if you use that?

Comment: no... I added console.logs for app and net and they appear undefined.. it's  like the whole script can't see electron. The script is included inside index.html using require('./renderer.js')

Comment: nvm found out why, i have to use the "remote" feature..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `{}` allow you to 'extract' the `app` property from the object you're requiring.

It is a feature of ECMAScript 2015 (a.k.a. ES6 or ES2015) called [Destructuring assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment). The following two lines are equivalent:

```
const {app} = require('electron');
const app = require('electron').app;
```